# How to differentiating and storing the differentiated frames in a specified place

Tags: python, opencv, video

Have attached the source code for frame differentiating and storing the differentiated frames in a specified place but am getting an error in indentation of error..post this problem as a question in stack overflow..i am restricted to question for a particular period..upload the code too

**filename.py**

```
import cv2
import os
import glob 

def extractFrames(pathIn, pathOut):
os.mkdir(pathOut)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(pathIn)
count = 0

while (cap.isOpened()):

    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    current_frame_gray = cv2.cvtColor(current_frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    previous_frame_gray = cv2.cvtcolor(previous_frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    frame_diff = cv2.absdiff(current_frame_gray,previous_frame_gray)        
    if ret == True:

        print('Read %d frame: ' % count, ret)
        cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(pathOut, "frame{:d}.jpg".format(count)), frame_diff)  # save frame as JPEG file

        count += 1
    else:
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
def main():
extractFrames('C:/Users/yaazmoha/Desktop/BE PROJECT/INPUT/Tiger in field(1080P_HD).mp4', 'fd3')
if __name__=="__main__":
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed your code. You had some indentation errors. Since Python does not use braces like C++, it requires proper indentation to separate code.

```
import cv2
import os
import glob 

def extractFrames(pathIn, pathOut):
    os.mkdir(pathOut)

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(pathIn)
    count = 0

    while (cap.isOpened()):

        # Capture frame-by-frame
        ret, current_frame = cap.read()

        current_frame_gray = cv2.cvtColor(current_frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        if count > 1:
            previous_frame_gray = cv2.cvtcolor(previous_frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

            frame_diff = cv2.absdiff(current_frame_gray,previous_frame_gray)        
            if ret == True:

                print('Read %d frame: ' % count, ret)
                cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(pathOut, "frame{:d}.jpg".format(count)), frame_diff)  # save frame as JPEG file

                count += 1
            else:
                break

        previous_frame = current_frame

    # When everything done, release the capture
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

def main():
    extractFrames(r"C:\Users\mathesn\Downloads\Wildlife.mp4", 'fd3')

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

I took liberties to fix other sections of your code. But there are some other fixes that this code needs, like creating a directory only if it doesn't exist, maintaining a colored version of the frame so that `cv2.cvtColor()` does not fail, etc., but I''ll leave those to you.